# How to make a player lock on to one enemy in it's radius?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have setup a tower defense game and have gotten it so you can place towers down, and enemies come at you. But, the towers are dealing damage to ALL of the monsters in their radius. I want it so that the towers only deal damage to only one enemy that is surrounding it.

I have setup two variables: monsterList, and towerList. They are both objects, and I have set it up so that on a certain event, it will add an enemy or a tower to the specified variable. So, when you select an empty area to set down a tower, it will add an object variable to the list. This will also happen when you click next level, but it creates dynamic monsters that can move through the path. It looks kind of like this:

```
//the variables
var monsterList = {};
var towerList = {};

//how towers or enemies are added
var Monster = {
    x:10,
    y:10,
    type:"Red",
    id:Math.random()
}
monsterList[Monster.id] = Monster;
```

So, that is how I create the monsters and the same way, but with different arguments, for a tower. When a monster goes down the path and gets within the tower's reach, the tower will attack any and all monsters within it's reach. I want it to only lock onto 1 monster within it's reach. Here is how I have my collision setup:

```
//loops through all the monsters and towers and tests if any of them are
//colliding. If they are colliding, it will decrease the monster's health by 
//1/30 of the tower's damage. This is because I have an interval looping 
//through this code 30 times a second. So, it deals the damage per second.
for(var key in monsterList){

    for(var i in towerList){

        if( Collision(towerList[i], monsterList[key]) ){
            monsterList[key].health -= ( towerList[i].damage/30 );
        }

        if( monsterList[key].health <= 0 ) delete monsterList[key];
    }
}
//and this is the Collision() function. It pretty much returns true if the
//monster is within the tower's range which is defined by an argument to the 
//tower called radius.
function Collision(tower, monster){
    return ((monster.y >= (tower.y - tower.radius*20)) &&
    (monster.x >= (tower.x - tower.radius*20)) &&
    (monster.y <= (tower.y + tower.height + tower.radius*20)) &&
    (monster.x <= (tower.x + tower.width + tower.radius*20)));
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: existing answers seem to have issues. So, if there are multiple in range WHICH ONE do you want to damage? The closest? The newest? The healthiest? The weakest?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey 's question is important, please answer it. You need to handle a `currentTarget` for each tower and to have a `selectTarget` method that will update `currentTarget` based on your selection strategy + the current game status.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this on your towers:

```
var tower = {
  ... //your tower properties
  target: null
}
```

and then on your loop:

```
for(var key in monsterList){
    for(var i in towerList) {

        if( !towerList[i].target && Collision(towerList[i], monsterList[key]) ) {
            towerList[i].target = key;
            monsterList[key].health -= ( towerList[i].damage/30 );
        }

        if( towerList[i].target ) {
            monsterList[towerList[i].target].health -= ( towerList[i].damage/30 );
        }

        if( monsterList[key].health <= 0 )
          delete monsterList[key];
    }
}
```

and you could also write the loop in a more readable way:

```
monsterList.forEach(function(monster) {

    towerList.forEach(function(tower) {
        if (!tower.target && Collision(tower, monster)
            tower.target = monster

        if (tower.target)
            tower.target.health -= tower.damage / 30;

        if (tower.target.health <= 0) {
            var monsterIndex = monsterList.indexOf(tower.target);
            delete monsterList[monsterIndex];
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yup, that is pretty much the same conclusion that I came to, except I wrote my suggestion in C#.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion I might have is to redesign your tower class to include a member that tracks which monster that tower is on.

```
    public void Main() {
        List<Tower> towers = new List<Tower>();
        List<Monster> monsters = new List<Monster>();
        foreach(var tower in towers) {
            if(tower.monsterTargeted==null) {//Find monster in range
                tower.monsterTargeted=monsters.FindAll(x => GetDistance(tower.location,x.location)<tower.range).OrderBy(x => GetDistance(tower.location,x.location)).FirstOrDefault();//can be null
            }
            if(tower.monsterTargeted!=null) {//attack targeted monster
                DamageMonster(tower.monsterTargeted.MonsterID,tower.damage);
            }
        }
    }

    private double GetDistance(Point p1,Point p2) {
        double x = p1.X-p2.X;
        double y = p1.Y-p2.Y;
        return Math.Sqrt(x*x+y*y);
    }

    private class Monster {
        public long MonsterID;
        public Point location;
    }

    private class Tower {
        public Monster monsterTargeted;
        public Point location;
        public double range;
        public double damage;
    }
```

Granted, this is C# code, but the theory is sound. Forcing your tower to track which monsters it is targeting enforces a many to one relationship between towers and monsters.